# find hyperlinks in reStructredText using docutils.parsers.rst

Tags: python, restructuredtext

For some internal consistency checking tool, I am trying to assemble a list of all hyperlinks (external references, images, etc ..) in an rst using python3.

I managed to parse the rst and walk the tree using the code below:

```
        parser = docutils.parsers.rst.Parser()
        components = (docutils.parsers.rst.Parser,)
        settings = docutils.frontend.OptionParser(components=components).get_default_values()
        document = docutils.utils.new_document('<rst-doc>', settings=settings)
        parser.parse(f, document)

        class MyVisitor(docutils.nodes.NodeVisitor):
            def visit_reference(self, node: docutils.nodes.reference) -> None:
                """Called for "reference" nodes."""
                print("reference", node)

            def unknown_visit(self, node: docutils.nodes.Node) -> None:
                """Called for all other node types."""
                print("unknown_visit", node)

        visitor = MyVisitor(document)
        document.walk(visitor)
```

However, I am now completely stuck on how to find references to images and external links (URLs) within the result.

Does anyone know how to retrieve these external links programmatically from the parsed document?

Answer (score 1):

Yes use a regular expression library

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp

You should be able to match for something like `(http[^\s]*)` which means match the text "http" followed by zero or more characters from the inverse set of whitespace (anything except a whitespace character)

Comment: good suggestion, but I was hoping for something context sensitive

Comment: @mirk what does context sensitive mean here? a solution that uses rst?

Comment: Something that can parse rst well enough to detect when a hyperlink is expected.